# Views position get incorrect when entering the screen

Tags: android

I have 4 views:

```
  <EditText
        android:id="@+id/loginEditTextPhone"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/loginEditTextPhoneWidth"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/loginTitle"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="-100dp"
        android:gravity="center"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/loginEditTextEmail"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/loginEditTextPhone"
        android:layout_below="@+id/loginEditTextPhone"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/loginEditTextEmailWidth"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/loginEditTextPass"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/loginEditTextPassWidth"
        android:layout_below="@+id/loginEditTextEmail"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/loginEditTextEmail"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/loginImgOk"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/loginEditTextPass"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/loginImgOkMarginTop"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

I set the first view (phone) offscreen using align_parentBottom and giving it a negative value.

As the other views are below the first view, they start off the screen as well.
Then, by clicking a button I have a an ObjectAnimator applying the exact same float value to all 4 views, so they can enter the screen.

I was hoping that the views would enter the screen and rest in the same distribution they are before the animation (one below the other), but what happens is that only first and the last one enter (2nd and 3rd views don't even show up), and besides that, the last one rests in a wrong position (higher than it should have rest).

I need to use ObjectAnimator since I depend on the actual view position.
What is happening here?

Here is the function I use for animation in this scenario:

```
public AnimatorSet buildSimultaneousAnimatorSetForPropertyX(View[] viewsToBeAnimated,
                                                            boolean isOffsetValue, float value, int time){

    ObjectAnimator objectAnimator;
    List<Animator> animatorList = new ArrayList<Animator>();

    for(View v : viewsToBeAnimated){
        if(isOffsetValue){
            objectAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(v, "x", v.getX() + (value));
        }else{
            objectAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(v, "x", value);
        }
        animatorList.add(objectAnimator);
    }
```

It returns an animator set for several views. Later on, I take the return and use as a parameter for another AnimatorSet.

Comment: can you show the java code for your animation?

Comment: I have included the function I built for the scenario